# Creating several lists where each has all items from original list in unique pairs

Tags: python, list, combinations, pairwise

I am trying to randomly pair two items from a list together in as many combinations as possible, then separate these into multiple lists where each item is included on each list and each pair is included exactly once in all the lists combined.

So for example if the following items were on the original list:
banana apple peach pear

I would want to produce the following as separate lists:

```
banana apple
peach pear

banana peach
apple pear

banana pear
apple peach
```

I added a list of 12 fruits then found every combination of pairs from the list using itertools. I made several new empty lists and created a for loop to check if either item in the pair has already been used in each list, and if it has to assign it to a new list:

```
fruitcombos = list(it.combinations(fruits, 2))

s1 = []
s2 = []
...
s10 = []

for group in fruitcombos:
    if not any(group[0] in x for x in s1) and not any(group[1] in x for x in s1):
            s1.append(group)
    elif not any(group[0] in x for x in s2) and not any(group[1] in x for x in s2):
            s2.append(group)
    elif not any(group[0] in x for x in s3) and not any(group[1] in x for x in s3):
            s3.append(group)
    ...
    
    elif not any(group[0] in x for x in s10) and not any(group[1] in x for x in s10):
            s10.append(group)
```

I've looked at the itertools module and tried round_robin, ncycles, sliding_window, and others but cannot figure out how to solve this problem in a more elegant way. It also isn't working properly - with the loop I've tried, the first list (s1) has 12 of the 12 items as expected. However other lists decrease in number, with the fourth list onwards only including 8 of the 12 items because parts of the other pairs have already been included in other lists. How would I avoid this?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't see why you will need to iterate and check if they are still in use if you already generated all possible combinations using itertools? Meaning if you used one pair in your list, you are already removing it out of the equation. like regardless of how you pair them, they are going to be unique. am i understanding it incorrectly?

Comment: What do you mean with _"as separate lists"_? each combination as a single list?

Comment: `combos = list(itertools.combinations(fruit_list, 2))` and `answer = [c1+c2 for c1,c2 in zip(combos, combos[::-1])]` and `return answer[:len(answer)//2]`

Comment: I am trying to assign each item from the input list to a unique pair in each output list. So each item will be included exactly once in each output list, and each pair in an output list will not be repeated in the other output lists. My list has about 40 items and I don't need every possible combination that would work, just about 10 output lists that meet the conditions

Answer (score 0):

```
In [4]: def partitions(L, k):
   ...:     combos = list(itertools.combinations(L, k))
   ...:     m = len(combos)//2
   ...:     return [c1+c2 for c1,c2 in zip(combos[:m], combos[m:][::-1])]
   ...:

In [5]: partitions('banana apple peach pear'.split(), 2)
Out[5]:
[('banana', 'apple', 'peach', 'pear'),
 ('banana', 'peach', 'apple', 'pear'),
 ('banana', 'pear', 'apple', 'peach')]
```

Or, alternatively

```
In [6]: def partitions(L, k):
   ...:     combos = list(itertools.combinations(L, k))
   ...:     m = len(combos)//2
   ...:     return list(zip(combos[:m], combos[m:][::-1]))
   ...:

In [7]: partitions('banana apple peach pear'.split(), 2)
Out[7]:
[(('banana', 'apple'), ('peach', 'pear')),
 (('banana', 'peach'), ('apple', 'pear')),
 (('banana', 'pear'), ('apple', 'peach'))]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This works with a list of four but I haven't been able to get it to work with a list of more than four (my actual input list will have about 40 items), as it only selects four items from the list each time rather than assigning each item from the list to a unique pair in each output list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example; I may have over-looked the reins.

Utilize the *[itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)* function, applying each to a *dictionary*.

```py
import itertools as i
l = ['banana', 'apple', 'peach', 'pear']
p = {(a, b): [c, d] for a, b, c, d in i.permutations(l, 4)}
```

Output

```
{('banana', 'apple'): ['pear', 'peach'],
 ('banana', 'peach'): ['pear', 'apple'],
 ('banana', 'pear'): ['peach', 'apple'],
 ('apple', 'banana'): ['pear', 'peach'],
 ('apple', 'peach'): ['pear', 'banana'],
 ('apple', 'pear'): ['peach', 'banana'],
 ('peach', 'banana'): ['pear', 'apple'],
 ('peach', 'apple'): ['pear', 'banana'],
 ('peach', 'pear'): ['apple', 'banana'],
 ('pear', 'banana'): ['peach', 'apple'],
 ('pear', 'apple'): ['peach', 'banana'],
 ('pear', 'peach'): ['apple', 'banana']}
```

---

Edit

> *"... I am trying to assign each item from the input list to a unique pair in each output list. So each item will be included exactly once in each output list, and each pair in an output list will not be repeated in the other output lists. ...
>
>
>
> ... my list has 40 items and increasing the list size does not yield unique pairs, do you know how this could be done?"*

Similarly, start by generating all combinations of pairs.
We'll limit the factor, by qualifying the iteration; in this case to, *"banana"*.

From here, traverse each pair, generating a filtered list.

```py
import itertools as i
l = ['banana', 'apple', 'peach', 'pear']
p = [(a, b) for a, b in i.combinations(l, 2) if a == l[0]]
d = {}
for k in p:
    v = zip(*[filter(lambda x: x not in k, l)] * 2)
    d.update({k: list(v)})
```

Output

```
{('banana', 'apple'): [('peach', 'pear')],
 ('banana', 'peach'): [('apple', 'pear')],
 ('banana', 'pear'): [('apple', 'peach')]}
```

Here is an output, for *a though z*.

```
{('a', 'b'): [('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h'), ('i', 'j'), ('k', 'l'), ('m', 'n'), ('o', 'p'), ('q', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'c'): [('b', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h'), ('i', 'j'), ('k', 'l'), ('m', 'n'), ('o', 'p'), ('q', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'd'): [('b', 'c'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h'), ('i', 'j'), ('k', 'l'), ('m', 'n'), ('o', 'p'), ('q', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'e'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'f'), ('g', 'h'), ('i', 'j'), ('k', 'l'), ('m', 'n'), ('o', 'p'), ('q', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'f'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('g', 'h'), ('i', 'j'), ('k', 'l'), ('m', 'n'), ('o', 'p'), ('q', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'g'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'h'), ('i', 'j'), ('k', 'l'), ('m', 'n'), ('o', 'p'), ('q', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'h'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('i', 'j'), ('k', 'l'), ('m', 'n'), ('o', 'p'), ('q', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'i'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'j'), ('k', 'l'), ('m', 'n'), ('o', 'p'), ('q', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'j'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('k', 'l'), ('m', 'n'), ('o', 'p'), ('q', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'k'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'l'), ('m', 'n'), ('o', 'p'), ('q', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'l'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('m', 'n'), ('o', 'p'), ('q', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'm'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('l', 'n'), ('o', 'p'), ('q', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'n'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('o', 'p'), ('q', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'o'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('n', 'p'), ('q', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'p'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('n', 'o'), ('q', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'q'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('n', 'o'), ('p', 'r'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'r'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('n', 'o'), ('p', 'q'), ('s', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 's'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('n', 'o'), ('p', 'q'), ('r', 't'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 't'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('n', 'o'), ('p', 'q'), ('r', 's'), ('u', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'u'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('n', 'o'), ('p', 'q'), ('r', 's'), ('t', 'v'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'v'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('n', 'o'), ('p', 'q'), ('r', 's'), ('t', 'u'), ('w', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'w'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('n', 'o'), ('p', 'q'), ('r', 's'), ('t', 'u'), ('v', 'x'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'x'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('n', 'o'), ('p', 'q'), ('r', 's'), ('t', 'u'), ('v', 'w'), ('y', 'z')],
 ('a', 'y'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('n', 'o'), ('p', 'q'), ('r', 's'), ('t', 'u'), ('v', 'w'), ('x', 'z')],
 ('a', 'z'): [('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('n', 'o'), ('p', 'q'), ('r', 's'), ('t', 'u'), ('v', 'w'), ('x', 'y')]}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've edited my question to clarify that I am trying to assign each item from the input list to a unique pair in each output list. So each item will be included exactly once in each output list, and each pair in an output list will not be repeated in the other output lists.  The first three items in your solution work for a 4-item list but my list has 40 items and increasing the list size does not yield unique pairs, do you know how this could be done?

Comment: @Keelin, no problem.  I've updated my answer.